# Rails 6, webpacker: image_pack_tag renders wrong image path, adds "assets/" to URI

Tags: image, tags, pack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

Working with new Rails 6 app using webpacker. Images are stored in `/app/frontend/images`.

```
//added to /app/frontend/application.js

const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Webpacker config:

```
/config/webpacker.yml contains:
default: &default
  source_path: app/frontend
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true
```

MY PROBLEM: `image_pack_tag` incorrectly adds `assets/` to image path.

`<%= image_pack_tag 'media/images/AdminLTELogo.png', alt: 'AdminLTE Logo', class: "brand-image img-circle elevation-3", style: "opacity: .8" %>`

Renders...
`<img alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8" src="/assets/%2Fpacks%2Fmedia%2Fimages%2FAdminLTELogo-28f7e31d41f353b3aaff1236c7108479.png">`

Removing `assets/` from the path will successfully render the image.

Any ideas what could be adding `assets/` to the image path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE CAUSE:
Just prior to this error I had created a model called 'asset'.  Somehow the `resources :assets` function in my routes.rb file conflicted with the `image_pack_tag`, inserting `assets/` in the path for all images.  I realized this when I simply commented out the `resources :assets` line in my routes.rb file, and all the images loaded properly.

THE SOLUTION:
I namespaced my asset model and also namespaced the `resources :assets` line in my routes.rb file.  All images load correctly now.